# Maven clean causes spring app run to fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I guess there is something I don't quite understand about the `mvn clean` command.

I use `mvn spring-boot:run` to run my Spring App, but whenever I run `mvn clean`, running `mvn spring-boot:run` right away returns the following :

[image: mvn clean error]

When I run my app before cleaning my app, it works just fine.

Someone I know that has more Spring Apps experience than me, told me to use `mvn clean` before running my app whenever I make a major change (dependencies etc).

Any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: The error message clearly gives you a hint. You might have only a JRE, and not a JDK.

Comment: I get that, but then why does it work when I run a `mvn spring-bot:run` before running `mvn clean` ? or maybe there is something else that I don't know / understand ?

Comment: Maybe `mvn spring-boot:run` does not need a compiler, and thus no JDK?

Comment: The answer of your question is in the answer below. Maven **needs** (necessarily) a JDK to be set. Read the answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this error happens when maven cannot find a suitable JDK. When you run

```
  $ mvn clean ...
```

Maven delete the target `folder`, therefore the `.jar` file and all the classes resulting from the compilation cycle. Therefore when you ask maven to run your application it needs to compile and package you application again. That is the reason why you need a JDK installed.

Your best guesses are:

1. You have not installed yet a JDK
2. The JDK has been installed, but you have not defined the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` (for linux or Mac: `export JAVA_HOME=path/to/java/folder`)
3. You have done the above, but you have not close and reopened the `terminal` (or `command line`)

I hope this might shed some light